# Why the Apache Spark programming guide keeps using SparkContext?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to write a new Spark 2 program. According to Apache Spark RDD-programming-guide, I should first create a SparkContext. 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#initializing-spark.
However, I know SparkSession is the gateway to all contexts in Spark 2. Is there a reason to not use SparkSession for any of my future Spark 2 programs?

Comment: There is no reason not to use `SparkSession` and there is no reason not to use dataframes instead of RDD. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html

Comment: So, is the documentation out of date or misleading? it still recommends to use SparkContext